# how do I get the data panel?

Tags: interface

Am using a more modern version of a tutorial I am following but the layout is different in it but I am trying to find the data panel which the mouse cursor is on from the older blender version tutorial: http://www.imagebam.com/image/16a7611354972651

this is my current part of that screen: http://www.imagebam.com/image/9d1aad1354972723

how can I find it please.

Comment: You first need to select an object if you want to see the Object Data tab

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)